# Giving href url location for parent window from child window

Tags: javascript

When I click logout in my page, it calls the logout.php for twitter logout. The below coding opens the twitter logout window in a child window and refreshes the same parent window for logout.

Also the user clicks the signout button in child window, they are logged out from twitter.
What I want to do here is, have to give a URL for the parent window when it refreshing.

When the parent window refreshes, it stays the URL
 **"www.example.com/sitename/index.php"**.

I want to change the URL as
 **"http://example.com/sitename/index.php"**. 
Since I had a problem with URL starts with WWW in my site

Anybody can help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

**Logout.php**

```
<?php
include("header.php");
    header("Location:https://twitter.com/#!/logout");
?>

<script>

function refreshParent()
{

  window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;

  if (window.opener.progressWindow)

  {
    window.opener.progressWindow.close()
  }
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: `a.b = a.b; // what?` reload would be much cleaner, imo.

Comment: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?129299-Can-t-refresh-reload-parent-window

This is the coding I taken from above URL for parent window refresh

Comment: You can use ** window.opener.location.reload(true); **, also you can solve your domain start from WWW problem with apache.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. can you explain me using example code

Comment: Please have a look I just post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put these lines in your root .htaccess file, to make non www request to www request.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But there is no option for redirecting the parent window in my code?

Comment: This is the solution to make all your website request to WWW

Comment: But what I want here is,

In my site the default URL starts from "mysite.com/index.php". But after twitter login and logout the URL starts from "www.mysite.com/index.php". So I want to remove the **www** after logout from twitter. This is wat I want. But really thanks for your kind reply. Great answers

Comment: Ok, do this window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href.replace(/www\./, "");

Comment: Checkout the twitter setting there must be an option for logout URL.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the problem is giving URL when we click the logout in main page.
We have to give the coding below when we write coding for session destroy

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=<?php echo URLPATH;?>">
```

This URLPATH is our mentioned URL so that after logout the parent window get refreshed with this URL and no need to write function seperately